# Concatenating a complex string in VB. NET

Tags: vb.net, string, concatenation, process.start

I am using `START-PROCESS` to call `MSTEST` with multiple arguments that define the container and test settings, however I think it's choking on the way I'm concatenating this. Should I use some other method of constructing this string before putting it into `START-PROCESS`?

```
Dim rwSettings As String = "\\PerfvsCtlr2\LoadtestSettings\PerfVSCtlr2forRemote.testsettings"
Dim rwContainer As String = "\\PerfvsCtlr2\LoadTest\LoadTestDefs\Heifer_Interactive_Peak_Workload.loadtest"
Dim rwResults As String = Workload.txtRwResults.Text
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("VS110COMNTOOLS") & "..\Ide\MSTEST.EXE", "/Testsettings:""" & rwSettings & "" & " /Testcontainer:""" & rwContainer & "" & " /Resultsfile:""" & rwResults & "")
```

The problem is unknown currently, because process.start opens and closes the window far too quickly for me to catch any sort of error message. So my question is two-fold:

Does the above concatenation look correct? Is there a way I can get more information on either the final execution string `Process.Start` is putting together or the error message it's returning?

Comment: Oh, d'oh. I forgot that didn't I. I'll edit the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Path.Combine` to build paths and `String.Format` to build the arguments for `Process.Start`:

```
Dim rwSettings As String = "\\PerfvsCtlr2\LoadtestSettings\PerfVSCtlr2forRemote.testsettings"
Dim rwContainer As String = "\\PerfvsCtlr2\LoadTest\LoadTestDefs\Heifer_Interactive_Peak_Workload.loadtest"
Dim rwResults As String = "Workload.txtRwResults.Text"

Dim fileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("VS110COMNTOOLS"), "Ide\MSTEST.EXE")
Dim args = String.Format("/Testsettings:{0} /Testcontainer:{1} /Resultsfile:{2}", rwSettings, rwContainer, rwResults)

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(fileName, args)
```

However, i must admit thar i'm not sure if this yields the desired result. It might give you an idea anyway.

Comment: Don't forget the quotes around the arguments :)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your problem is that you are not closing your quotation marks, for instance:

```
" /Testcontainer:""" & rwContainer & ""
```

Should be:

```
" /Testcontainer:""" & rwContainer & """"
```

Notice that the double-quotation mark at the end needs to be a quadruple quotation mark.  Simply saying `""` means an empty string.

Should you use something else?  Probably.  It would be more readable and efficient if you used `StringBuilder` or `String.Format`, but even so, you'll still have to fix the closing quotes issue.

Comment: That's exactly what it was, but the fact that I was having so much trouble with simple quotation marks shows I should make it more easily readable. I'll look into StringBuilder and String.Format.